# How to get value of a tag?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html on my asp.net page and I would like to get just the value within the p tag using jquery.

```
<p><pi>€ </pi>213,47</p>
```

I tried the following

```
var Product = {};
Product.Price = $(this).closest(".caption").find("p:eq(0)").html();
```

But this gives me `"<pi>€ </pi>213,47"` but I want to get just the value `213,47`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var Product = {};
Product.Price = $(this).closest(".caption").find("p:eq(0)").text().replace('€','');
```

**Update**

Since jQuery 3.4 `:eq` selector is not supported, so it should not used be anymore. As an alternative you can use `.eq(0)` instead of `:eq(0)`:

```
var Product = {};
Product.Price = $(this).closest(".caption").find("p").eq(0).text().replace('€','');
```

Comment: `:eq` is a deprecated function since jQuery 3.4 and should not be used. Just FYI

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks for your notice. I update the answer :).

Comment: `:first` is a deprecated function as well. Use `.eq(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You could get the [`text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) of `pi` and remove it from `p`, *i.e.*

```js
let pi = $('p > pi').text();
let p = $('p').text();
console.log(p.replace(pi, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><pi>€ </pi>213,47</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, for example...

```
var p = $('p');
var price = p.html().replace(/<pi>[^<]*<\/pi>/, '');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0hLxje8z/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```js
var Product = {};
var caption = $(".caption"); // change this with your selector
Product.Price = caption.find("p").eq(0).text();
console.log(Product)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="caption">
  <p>
    <pi>€ </pi>213,47</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `:eq` is a deprecated function since jQuery 3.4 and should not be used. Just FYI